# Receiving and internal server error 500 when making a post request from a google cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-fetch

I actually found this exact question on the site previously, however the solution for their problem did not solve mine.

Below is my code for my google cloud function:

```
exports.makeOrder = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { session: sessionId, products: lineItems } = req;
    const session = await fetch(
      `${API}v1/checkout/sessions/${sessionId}`,
      options
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    const customer = await fetch(
      `${API}v1/customers/${session.customer}`,
      options
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    const fullName = session.shipping.name;
    const splitName = fullName.split(' ');
    const firstName = splitName[0];
    const lastName = splitName[1];
    const printifyOrder = {
      external_id: session.customer,
      line_items: lineItems,
      shipping_method: 1,
      send_shipping_notification: true,
      address_to: {
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName,
        email: customer.email,
        country: session.shipping.address.country,
        region: session.shipping.address.state,
        address1: session.shipping.address.line1,
        address2: session.shipping.address.line2,
        city: session.shipping.address.city,
        zip: session.shipping.address.postal_code,
      },
    };
    // This is where my code stops working
    fetch(`${pUrl}shops/${shopId}/orders.json`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(printifyOrder),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ` + apiKey,
      },
    }).then(res => res.json()).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I am currently trying to call this function in my react component passing in the data I destructured at the top. currently I am receiving an internal server error in the console as seen here:

```
>  Response {
>    size: 0,
>    timeout: 0,
>    [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
>      body: Gunzip {
>        _writeState: [Uint32Array],
>        _readableState: [ReadableState],
>        readable: true,
>        _events: [Object: null prototype],
>        _eventsCount: 6,
>        _maxListeners: undefined,
>        _writableState: [WritableState],
>        writable: false,
>        allowHalfOpen: true,
>        _transformState: [Object],
>        _hadError: false,
>        bytesWritten: 0,
>        _handle: [Zlib],
>        _outBuffer: <Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 0a 20 20 20 20 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 ... 16334 more bytes>,
>        _outOffset: 0,
>        _chunkSize: 16384,
>        _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
>        _finishFlushFlag: 2,
>        _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
>        _info: undefined,
>        _level: -1,
>        _strategy: 0,
>        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
>      },
>      disturbed: false,
>      error: null
>    },
>    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
>      url: 'https://api.printify.com/v1/shops/{shopId}/orders.json', // I removed the shop ID from this line in case you think this is my issue
>      status: 500,
>      statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
>      headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
>      counter: 0
>    }
>  }
```

When I do a `console.log()` of my `printifyOrder` it logs all the correct data. I have tried making this call with an `onCall` function as seen here using node-fetch as well as axios, and I have tried running it by triggering it inside of an express app, all attempts returned the same result.

Here also is my client side code where I am am calling the function:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { firebase } from '../configs/config'
const makeOrder = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('makeOrder');

const CheckoutSuccess = () => {
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const { cartItems } = cart
    const printifyProducts = [];
    cartItems.forEach(product => {
        const printifyProduct = {
            sku: product.sku,
            qty: product.qty
          }
          printifyProducts.push(printifyProduct)
    });
    
    const url = window.location.href;
    const sessionId = new URL(url).searchParams.get('session_id')

    const data = {
        products: printifyProducts,
        session: sessionId
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        makeOrder(data)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}


export { CheckoutSuccess }
```

Also when I try running this exact function locally through node in the terminal it will post to the API and I can see the result almost immediately. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have trace log on your Cloud Functions?

Comment: Please edit the question to show 1) the client code making the request, and 2) any errors from the Cloud Functions console.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added my client side code where i call the function. And I have already put in my cloud function console error in my post, it's the second code block. Like I mentioned in my post though I can receive the data from the client side and I can even log out my order, but It won't post.

Comment: If you are still having this error, you could contact the corresponding team of [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) in order to investigate your issue.